# How to force a line break after each image in Safari Reader?

Tags: html, safari

I was unable to activate Safari Reader in a local HTML file, so I cannot give you a running example but only describe my problem:

The markup of my blog posts is basically this:

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="post-header">Hello, World</div>
 <div class="post-body">
  <p>Look at this picture:</p>
  <p><img src="http://37prime.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/safari_icon.png"/></p>
  <p>Isn't that a nice picture?</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This looks as expected in all browsers, including Safari. In Safari Reader however, the third paragraph "Isn't that a nice picture?" is floating around the image, instead of being on a paragraph of it's own.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem?

Comment: I ignored this problem for a while (sadly, none your suggestions worked for me) and just tried it out again in Safari Reader out of curiosity. For some reason, the problem does _not_ occur anymore. In the mean time, I made several changes to my CSS, so my original CSS probably caused the problems (That or it was a bug in Safari and I didn't notice it updating itself).

Answer (score 27):

Don't just use `<br />`, but `<br clear="all" />`.

Comment: Wow. Nice property

Answer (score 13):

```
.post-body img {
  display: block;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src='ImagePath' alt="not found" style="display:block">
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `<br/>` tag at the end/after each line

Comment: See my comment to Taylor Satula's answer. In a nutshell: It doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you could try to put a <br>  line break in after "picture:"
I can't verify that it works but in theory it world fix the problem by using a tag made just for line breaks (shrinking the chance that it's re styled)

Comment: When I insert a <br/>, Safari Reader does not recognise the article anymore for some reason. Anyways, it's not as if I could easily put a <br/> behind each image anyways: The articles are marked up via Textile and the line breaks would have to be set by each author explicitly.

Comment: As already mentioned by @fhd, it doesn’t work. In addition, adding an answer which you haven’t verified works, is not of much use for the site and its user, unless the question is about the theoretical approach (as you do mention).